# Blank screen after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: linux, boot, drivers, linux-mint

Running Mint 18.3, clean install. Left everything to defaults. After installation, the only actions taken were:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo reboot now
```

Second session:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-387
sudo reboot now
```

After this, the system would make it past GRUB and to the splash screen, before going blank.

Solutions attempted:

1: Ctrl + Shift + F1 does not send me to a command line, nor do any other F keys

2: Setting kernel parameters to include nomodeset

3: Setting grub_gfxmode=1024x768x16

4: Using nvidia-384 on another clean install

I disabled quiet and splash from the kernel parameters as well, in case I could find any information in the messages. The last message seen before the screen goes blank is:

```
[OK] Started Light Display Manager
```

I had another copy of Mint running as intended on a separate drive. That drive was disconnected before installing this current operating system on a newer drive.

EDIT: Video cards: 4x GTX 1080

Comment: And your Nvidia Graphics card is...?

Comment: Oh, that's embarrassing. 4x GTX 1080

Comment: Try 390 after purging the previous drivers.

Comment: apt purge nvidia* does not help, unfortunately. That, and there's nothing to remove on a clean install.